# Package datatool Error: \DTLforeach nested too deeply

Tags: datatool

I'm using datatool, and I have tried to nest the \DTLforeach function four times, to create multiple tables from various csv files. Naturally the title error comes up.

How come the \DTLforeach function is limited to a nesting depth of three only?

I could use Python or MATLAB to rearrange my data and slot it neatly into LaTeX, but is there a TeX-based workaround for this?

Comment: Can you post a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that uses 4 nestings? That way one can play around with attempts to correct it within LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`datatool`](//ctan.org/pkg/datatool) keeps track of a number of things for each level of nesting using macros of the form `\...i`, `\...ii`, `\...iii`, as well as counters for each level. You'll have to add all of the macros and counters for higher levels (`\...iv`, `\...v`, ...) as well as update the condition for testing the level depth (2 locations, one associated with `\DTLforeach` and one for `\DTLforeach*` as part of `\@sDTLforeach`).